# Submitting a file to Desire2Learn Dropbox

Tags: desire2learn

Trying to submit a file to the Dropbox through PHP to a Desire2Learn Learning Suite.  I don't see a field name documented to contain the file.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not missing something. There is no field name for the file for dropbox submissions. Leave the name attribute as an empty string when posting the submission file.

Here’s what a submission request should look like:

```
POST http://{domain_name}/d2l/api/le/{version}/{org_unit}/dropbox/folders/{folder_id}/submissions/mysubmissions/?x_a={app_id}&x_b={token_id}&x_d={token_sig}&x_c={app_sig}&x_t={time} HTTP/1.1  
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=8cf23611201b7ae  
Host: {domain_name}  
Content-Length: 775926

--8cf23611201b7ae  
Content-Type: application/json

{"Text":"Here you go","HTML":null}  
--8cf23611201b7ae  
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="Jellyfish.jpg"  
Content-Type: image/jpeg

{binary data}  
--8cf23611201b7ae--
```